# Could not find ISubscriptionService in Sitecore.Lisitmanagement.xconnect version 5.0.0.0

Tags: sitecore

I am using the official sitecore documentation(https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-list-manager-api.html) to add a contact to a conatctlist on my sitecore 9.3 environment.
But I get the error- Isubscriptionservice could not be found. I cannot find Isubscriptionservice  on  Sitecore.Lisitmanagement.xconnect namespace either.